# Caliburn Micro VS MVVM Light are these frameworks the same?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have to learn the Caliburn.Micro for my new project, and have some earlier experience with the mvvm light in my past projects. The question is what is the main difference between two these frameworks and how I need to start to learn the Caliburn.Micro 
in order to decrease the learning curve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biggest difference is the ability of CM to auto-bind to controls with x:Names that are generally built-in controls (not 3rd party) via conventions.  This allows for you to write properties for strings and voids for events.

`<Button x:Name="OpenWindow" />`

then in your viewmodel that corresponds to the view that this would be on would have a `public void OpenWindow(){}`.  There is also the ability to control execution of button clicks with guards.  `CanOpenWindow` could be a bool property or a method with parameters to Enable/Disable the button till it meets the conditions you put into `CanOpenWindow`, it is an abstraction of Execute/CanExecute from ICommand under the covers.

There is some overlap like messenger would be equivalent to IEventAggregator for passing events to other screens or entire application, functionally dependent on what you need.

IOC/DI is handled internally or you can use someone else's container.  built-in containers are MEF and SimpleContainer, there are 3rd party bootstrapper wrappers for AutoFac, Ninject, Winsor to name a few.

3.0 is presently in development for cross-platform development. Its really a pretty easy framework once you have the basic understanding of what it does behind the scenes, if you really want to know more https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro and http://caliburnmicro.com docs and samples.

hth

Morgan